# How to write javascript code in custom widget in VAADIN 6 client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vaadin

I am trying to make a simple widget that has a simple div and jquery applies in that. for that i have to write javascript code on client side of that widget. I tried to write javascript with the HTML but it doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
 public void updateFromUIDL(UIDL uidl, ApplicationConnection client) {
    // This call should be made first. 
    // It handles sizes, captions, tooltips, etc. automatically.
    if (client.updateComponent(this, uidl, true)) {
        // If client.updateComponent returns true there has been no changes and we
        // do not need to update anything.
        return;
    }

    // Save reference to server connection object to be able to send
    // user interaction later
    this.client = client;

    // Save the client side identifier (paintable id) for the widget
    paintableId = uidl.getId();

    // Process attributes/variables from the server
    // The attribute names are the same as we used in 
    // paintContent on the server-side
    int clicks = uidl.getIntAttribute("clicks");
    String message = uidl.getStringAttribute("message");
    String myScript = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function(){$('#mytest').click(function(){alert('Clicked')})})</script>";

    getElement().setInnerHTML(myScript+"<div id='mytest'>Click me</div>");
    //getElement().setInnerHTML("After <b>"+clicks+"</b> mouse clicks:\n" + message);

}
```

in browser inspect element HTML is like this
[image]

but this alert does not show up. How to do it. please help. im tired of doing google this problem.
I am using Vaadin 6

Thank you

Comment: The $(document).ready(..) is either not included (Missing jQuery JS files) or it does not get fired because the UIDL update is done afterwards

Comment: sorry, i didn't mention that jQuery lib files are loaded. it does fire because we can see script added with the div in Inspect element(I have attached a screen shot with it). Anyways, thanks for your reply